# Spark 2.0: Redefining SparkSession params through GetOrCreate and NOT seeing changes in WebUI

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.0 with PySpark.

I am redefining `SparkSession` parameters through a `GetOrCreate` method that was introduced in 2.0:

> This method first checks whether there is a valid global default SparkSession, and if yes, return that one. If no valid global default SparkSession exists, the method creates a new SparkSession and assigns the newly created SparkSession as the global default.
>
> In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the config options specified in this builder will be applied to the existing SparkSession.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate

So far so good:

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf

SparkConf().toDebugString()
'spark.app.name=pyspark-shell\nspark.master=local[2]\nspark.submit.deployMode=client'

spark.conf.get("spark.app.name")
'pyspark-shell'
```

Then I redefine `SparkSession` config with the promise to see the changes in WebUI

> appName(name)
> Sets a name for the application, which will be shown in the Spark web UI.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder.appName

```py
c = SparkConf()
(c
 .setAppName("MyApp")
 .setMaster("local")
 .set("spark.driver.memory","1g")
 )

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
(SparkSession
.builder
.enableHiveSupport() # metastore, serdes, Hive udf
.config(conf=c)
.getOrCreate())

spark.conf.get("spark.app.name")
'MyApp'
```

Now, when I go to `localhost:4040`, I would expect to see `MyApp` as an app name.

However, I still see `pyspark-shell application UI`

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that documentation is a bit misleading here and when you work with Scala you actually see a warning like this:

```
... WARN SparkSession$Builder: Use an existing SparkSession, some configuration may not take effect.
```

It was more obvious prior to Spark 2.0 with clear separation between contexts:

- `SparkContext` configuration cannot be modified on runtime. You have to stop existing context first.
- `SQLContext` configuration can be modified on runtime.

`spark.app.name`, like many other options, is bound to `SparkContext`, and cannot be modified without stopping the context.

**Reusing existing `SparkContext` / `SparkSession`**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
```

```
String = 200
```

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("foo")
  .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2001")

val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
```

```
... WARN SparkSession$Builder: Use an existing SparkSession ...
spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession =  ...
```

```scala
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
```

```
String = 2001
```

While `spark.app.name` config is updated:

```scala
spark.conf.get("spark.app.name")
```

```
String = foo
```

it doesn't affect `SparkContext`:

```scala
spark.sparkContext.appName
```

```
String = Spark shell
```

**Stopping existing `SparkContext` / `SparkSession`**

Now let's stop the session and repeat the process:

```scala
spark.stop
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
```

```
...  WARN SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext ...
spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = ...
```

```scala
spark.sparkContext.appName
```

```
String = foo
```

Interestingly when we stop the session we still get a warning about using existing `SparkContext`, but you can check it is actually stopped.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and struggled with it for a long time, then find a simple solution:

spark.stop()

then build your new sparksession again