# what is the difference between sparksession.config() and spark.conf.set()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I tried use both ways to set `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors`, but it seems like that only the first way works

```py
spark2 = SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .appName("test") \
  .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", 15) \
  .getOrCreate()
```

vs.

```py
spark2.conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", 15)
```

Answer (score 8):

It is not so much about the difference between the methods, as the difference in the context in which these are executed.

- `pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession.Builder` options can be executed before Spark application has been started. This means that, if there is no active `SparkSession` to be retrieved, some cluster specific options can be still set.

  If the session was already initialized setting new config options might not work. See for example [Spark 2.0: Redefining SparkSession params through GetOrCreate and NOT seeing changes in WebUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40701518/6910411)
- `pyspark.sql.conf.RuntimeConfig` can be retrieved only from exiting session, therefore its `set` method is called once the cluster is running. At this point majority of cluster specific options are frozen and cannot be modified.

In general `RuntimeConfig.set` is used to modify `spark.sql.*` configuration parameters, which normally can be changed on runtime.

Please note, that depending on the deployment mode, some options (most notably `spark.*.extraJavaOptions`) cannot be set using any of these methods, and can be modified only through `spark-submit` arguments or using configuration files.

Comment: great to point out here the `RuntimeConfig.set` modifies `spark.sql.*`

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd rather wanted to ask why certain configurations (e.g. `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors`) cannot be set using `spark2.conf.set` vs `SparkSession.config`?

`spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` is to control how to execute Spark jobs, most importantly to control the number of executors and as such should not be set within a Spark application. I'm even surprised to hear that it worked at all. It should not really IMHO.

The reason why this and some other configurations should not be set within a Spark application is that they control the execution environment for the underlying Spark runtime (that worked behind the scenes of Spark SQL) and as such should be changed using `spark-submit` that is more for application deployers or admins than developers themselves. Whether dynamic allocation (of executors) is used or not has no impact on the business use of Spark and is a decision to be made after the application is developed.

With that said, let me answer your question directly, some configurations require to be set before a `SparkSession` instance is created as they control how this instance is going to be instantiated. Once you created the instance, when you call `spark2.conf` the instance is already configured and some configurations cannot be changed ever. It seems that `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` is among the configurations that cannot be changed after an instance of `SparkSession` has been created. And given what I said earlier I'm happy to hear that this is the case (but unfortunately not in all cases).

Answer (score 0):

Some config properties need to be set before the SparkSession starts for them to work. Sparksession uses them at the time of initialization. If u set spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors after the creation of sparksession there will still be a change in the value for that property in sparConf object and u can verify that by printing the property but it does not affect the sparksession session as it took the value present at the time of the initialization.